# How to mimic Google Analytics utmz-cookie creation?

Tags: php, google-analytics, seo, universal-analytics

Now we are using standard google analytics script dc.js to create utm-cookies by http referrer and http url of the visitor. Now google stops creating utm-cookies since Universal Analytics.

Is there any way to mimic utm-cookie creation logic by referer and url using internal or external solution?

PS. Please, don't advise to get rid of utm-cookies. The main question is: "is it possible to create cookies by the same logic which google does?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not realy easy. You can use the PHP function `$_SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER']` but:

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

As far as I know, the Universal Analytics HAS a way of tracking referrals using `_ga` cookies and it works very nice. If you work with PHP (hosted GA), then you will have problems but with JavaScript woks fine.

If you whant to follow AND `_utm` cookies with javascript, you need to create some "push" script what will collect that data but I think Universal Analytic have that option automaticly.

Read **[THIS](http://www.optimizesmart.com/google-analytics-cookies-ultimate-guide/)** blog please.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunatelly this link - http://www.optimizesmart.com/google-analytics-cookies-ultimate-guide/ has no explanation about utmz_* creation. I found this explanation very usefull - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/campaign-flow

Comment: Ah yes. I forgot about this. I send you that link becouse there is a lot explanation about GA functionality. Only problem about utmz cookie can be encoding. Some characters like comma and dot can be encoded automaticly